# Is there any research paper state the pros and cons for human to be taller?

Tags: human-biology

Is there any research paper state the physical health pros and physical health cons for humans to be taller?

For example, shorter people seems to more likely to get involved in heart diseases and taller people to be more likely to be involved in cancer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**People with Shorter height may outlive Taller ones**.

It is a statistically established fact that they are more successful in terms of money, 
as the study published *Journal of Applied Psychology, (Vol 89(3), Jun 2004, 428-441)*.
But, still in the health, the counterpart succeed over the former.

> **The Effect of Physical Height on Workplace Success and Income: Preliminary Test of a Theoretical Model.**
>
> - Author: Judge, Timothy A.; Cable, Daniel M.
>
> In this article, the authors propose a theoretical model of the
>   relationship between physical height and career success. We then test
>   several linkages in the model based on a meta-analysis of the
>   literature, with results indicating that physical height is
>   significantly related to measures of social esteem (p = .41), leader
>   emergence (p = .24), and performance (p = .18). Height was somewhat
>   more strongly related to success for men (p = .29) than for women (p =
>   .21), although this difference was not significant. Finally, given
>   that almost no research has examined the relationship between
>   individuals' physical height and their incomes, we present four
>   large-sample studies (total N = 8,590) showing that height is
>   positively related to income (β = .26) after controlling for sex, age,
>   and weight. Overall, this article presents the most comprehensive
>   analysis of the relationship of height to workplace success to date,
>   and the results suggest that tall individuals have advantages in
>   several important aspects of their careers and organizational lives.
>   (PsycINFO Database Record (c) 2012 APA, all rights reserved)
>   Source: http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/apl/89/3/428/

---

Long back in 1975, the relationship between breast cancer and height had been nearly established.

> ### **Breast Cancer Incidence and Nutritional Status with Particular Reference to Body Weight and Height**
>
> **Author**: F. de Waard
>
> *Cancer Res 1975;35:3351-3356.*
>
> **Summary** The epidemiological literature on breast cancer is reviewed with particular emphasis on the possible etiological role of
>   nutritional status as reflected by weight and height. The results of a
>   prospective study and preliminary results of a population-based
>   case-control study seem to indicate that body size or body mass rather
>   than overweight (obesity) is a risk factor. A considerable proportion
>   of the differences in incidence between the Netherlands and Japan can
>   be explained by differences in body mass. The biological mechanisms
>   mediating nutritional status and breast cancer are believed to be of
>   an endocrinological- metabolic nature.

[image]

Primarily the investigators started with overweight problem but they have found a better correlation with height. They have concluded:

> A further lead to biological mechanisms might be derived
>   from the fact that several endocrine and metabolic functions
>   (e.g., basal metabolic rate and cortisol production rate)
>   seem to correlate better with body surface area than with
>   body weight. The rationale for using surface area is often
>   lacking except for the fact that it is estimated from both
>   weight and height.

### Height and cancer risk are fairly clearly linked, with a 16 per cent higher relative risk for every extra 4 inches of height.

The answer may lies in the metabolic rate:

> For one, taller people tend to weigh more than shorter people, even if
>   their BMI isn’t any higher. For another, poor nutrition and stress can
>   stunt height growth, and higher calorie diets have been associated
>   with increased height. And that doesn’t even begin to take into
>   account the psychosocial variables like increased income, education,
>   and socioeconomic status.

---

### **Other Diseases**

On the contrary, in a study examining cardiovascular disease risk and height in men found that men who were taller than 6′ 1″ (185 cm) had a 35% lower risk of having a heart attack than men who were shorter than 5′ 7″ (170 cm). Every inch a man gained in height resulted in a 2-3% decrease in heart attack risk.
In a study in among, Israeli civil servants, shows height was also associated with lower stroke risk. Taller people are more likely,around 76%,  to suffer from recurrent blood clots.

LINKS:

- http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/crux/2013/11/08/is-being-tall-hazardous-to-your-health/#.U79p3vmSzQJ
- http://scienceblog.cancerresearchuk.org/2011/07/21/height-and-cancer-risk-%E2%80%93-the-long-and-short-of-it/

Comment: Link-only answers can become obsolete if the content changes or the page disappears. Instead, please summarize the information found in the link in the body of your answer, and provide the link for reference. The answer should be able to stand on its own without the external resource.